# NetSuite - Deleting Time Entry Records

Tags: netsuite

Has anyone figured out a way to delete a time entry record from a time sheet record, without actually deleting the time sheet?  My use case is that I have been syncing work time from JIRA to NetSuite for over a year now.  When there is an error or they need to update their time, my integration just deletes it and recreates everything.  Never an issue, since the time sheets are not submitted or approved yet, at that point.

Now, we have installed this SuitePeople bundle (sadly, the project managers working on that did not test anything...:/ ), which has completely changed time tracking.  Aside from custom fields no longer showing up in the columns (a whole different issue), they are now generating generic timesheets for people to show time off.  Those time sheets are not able to be deleted, and their time entries are not able to even be edited (presumably since they were created by the system - at least that's what NetSuite says).

My last hope is to add/edit/delete time entry records when the additional system generated time sheets have been added.  But, anytime I try to delete a time entry, I'm given the error that timeentry is not a valid record type (since it is a subrecord).

Any thoughts?  Feeling completely at a loss here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I had to run this through a RESTlet, where SuiteScript is able to directly search and delete time entry records.  Here are the important parts of that script, in case anyone runs into this as well.

```
var timeEntrySearch=search.create({
  type:'timeentry',
  columns:[{name:'employee'},{name:'hours'},{name:'internalid'},{name:'memo'}],
  filters:[{name:'date',operator:'within',values:[startDate,endDate]},{name:'employee',operator:'is',values:[userID]}]
}).run().each(function(result){
  log.debug('results',JSON.stringify(result));
  var memoField=result.getValue({name:'memo'});
  if(memoField.indexOf('JIRA Time')!=-1){responseArray.push(result);}
  return true;
});

for(var el in responseArray){
  try{
    log.debug('Deleting',JSON.stringify(responseArray[el].id));
    record.delete({type:'timeentry',id:responseArray[el].id});
  }catch(deleteErr01){
    log.debug('ERROR[deleteErr01]',JSON.stringify(deleteErr01));
    continue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is good to know since I have a direct integration with JIRA worklogs as well but no SuitePeople.

Can you cancel/reject the timesheet?

Comment: Nope, not anymore.  Via the UI, I can edit, and change the status.  And, if I add new ones I can remove those.  But, via web services and scripting I'm getting errors that there is no such record as a timeentry.  Which, kind of makes sense, as it is a subrecord.  But, these SuitePeople entries are essentially locking the actual timesheet down to where you can't change it. :/